# Aligning Text in android Email Intent

Tags: android, html, html-email

I am working on an application in which I have some default text to be sent to some friend through email. To serve the purpose, I am defining the default Text as HTML string using (text/html) as intent type. I am having a problem aligning the text to center. All other tags are working except alignment related tags.

This is what I am doing to align the text to the center of the email body:

```
 <center>
  <p style='font-family:Helvetica-Bold;font-size:10.5pt;color: black'>rob </p>
 </center>
```

as well as:

```
<p style='text-align:center;font-family:Helvetica-Bold;font-size:10.5pt;color: black'>rob </p>
```

but neither of the approaches is paying off...the text still remains left align in email intent. However if I check it ion browser it is center aligned. How can I align the string to center i9n email intent html being used. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance...:-)

Comment: By Using 2nd technique add `!important` in your css like this: `text-align:center !important;` and let me know.

Comment: It did not have any effect...

Answer (score 0):

It seams that the `<p>`  tag is not supported.
[See this Reference.](http://nowherenearithaca.blogspot.ch/2011/10/some-notes-for-sending-html-email-in.html)

You will have to find another solution, did you try using `<div>` tags